# I own a genomic string, how to efficiently find the same part

Tags: python, bioinformatics

Supplemental Data Link:

- Candidates: https://pan.baidu.com/s/1nvGWbrV
- Bg_db: https://pan.baidu.com/s/1sllFLAd

Each string length is 23, as long as the front 20 characters on the line, because the data is too large, I only pass one-fifth of 1the , there are fast you can paste the code, let the brother read it, Thank you!

Here's the formal question:

I now have two string arrays, tentatively called `Candidates` and `Bg_db`, all of them are short strings of length 20, and each string only contains character among the following four: A, T, C, G (right! Is the genome sequence!):

```
Candidates = [
    'GGGAGCAGGCAAGGACTCTG',
    'GCTCGGGCTTGTCCACAGGA',
    '...',
    # Be you see, these fragments of human genes in fact
]

Bg_db = [
    'CTGCTGACGGGTGACACCCA',
    'AGGAACTGGTGCTTGATGGC',
    '...',
    # This more, there are about one billion
]
```

My task is to candidates for each candidate, to find all less than or equal `Bg_db` 4 differences in the record, for example:

```
# The above one for the candidate, that is, a record candidates
# Intermediate | represent the same, * represent not the same
# The following represents a record of Bg_db

A T C G A T C G A T C G A T C G A T C G
| | | | | | | |
A T C G A T C G A T C G A T C G A T C G

A T C G A T C G A T C G A T C G A T C G
* The difference is 1
T T C G A T C G A T C G A T C G A T C G

A T C G A T C G A T C G A T C G A T C G
* The difference is 2
T T C G T T C G A T C G A T C G A T C G

A T C G A T C G A T C G A T C G A T C G
* | | * | | | * | | | The difference is 3
T T C G T T C G A T C C A T C G A T C G

A T C G A T C G A T G G A T C G A T C G
* | | * | | | * | |
T T C G T T C G A T C C A T C A A T C G
```

My problem is if you quickly find: every candidate in `Bg_db` with a difference of less than or equal to 4 of all records, if the use of violent traversal, then Python as an example:

```
def align (candidate, record_from_bg_db):
    Mismatches = 0
    For i in range (20):
        If candidate [i]! = Record_from_bg_db [i]:
            Mismatches + = 1
            If mismatches> = 4:
                Return False
    Return True

Candidate = 'GGGAGCAGGCAAGGACTCTG'
Record_from_bg_db = 'CTGCTGACGGGTGACACCCA'

Align(candidate, record_from_bg_db) # 1.24 microseconds or so

# total time:

10000000 * 1000000000 * 1.24 / 1000/1000/60/60/24/365
# = 393
# 1 million candidates, 1 billion bg_db records
# Takes about 393 years
# Completely unbearable ah
```

My idea is that `Bg_db` is a highly ordered string (the length of each character may be only four), there is no algorithm that allows candidates to quickly compare all the `Bg_db`, seeking advice.

Comment: Your code if full of mis-placed capital letters and a few typos. However, I think your current approach in `align` is conceptually fine. If you want to speed it up you may need to depart from Python

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely ,I'll try.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing above is formally called the Hamming distance. You can read more here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance

To paraphrase opening statement in the above link:

> In information theory, the Hamming distance between two strings of
>   equal length is the number of positions at which the corresponding
>   symbols are different. In another way, it measures the minimum number
>   of substitutions required to change one string into the other, or the
>   minimum number of errors that could have transformed one string into
>   the other.

A simple way to improve on this would be to exit the string comparison when you observe > 4 mismatches, but that would only reduce run time when there are many string comparisons that contains a large number of mismatches.

Your other option is to use more recent algorithms, such as those that implement Burrow-Wheeler transform (BWT). See complete list here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sequence_alignment_software#Short-read_sequence_alignment

Using a BWT software tool, my suggestion would be to concatenate one of the sequence data sets into a single **target** sequence, then **query** it using the other set of short sequences.  Reason being that BWT algorithms typically works well when the **target** consists of a few large sequences, such as chromosomes from the human genome.  Once you obtain the alignments, you can filter out those alignments that span the positions where you joined the target sequences ie., alignments that span positions that are exact multiples of 20.

BWT-based tools are typically orders of magnitude faster than past DNA sequence alignment algorithms, and the usage case you present ie., ungapped alignment of short sequences, is what these programs were designed to optimize.

So, unless this is a homework assignment, I would recommend you research which software tool suits you needs best. Developing your own sequence alignment algorithm is difficult (from personal experience), and time spent in properly assessing existing tools will help you decide whether this time spent developing software is worthwhile.

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely ,I will read the information carefully.

Comment: It's a bit unclear whether @luyishisi wants to actually perform an alignment (where external software would be best) or merely count the mismatches between 2 already aligned gap-free sequences

Comment: I agree, hence the general reply. However, counting pairwise mismatches for such a large number is sequences may not be feasible, hence my suggestion to use more advanced gap-free aligners. Exact solution may not be possible as anything tried would require testing to ensure it satisfies requirements for accuracy and runtime.